# What does it mean for a website to return syn:false ack:true to my connect attempt?

Tags: tcp

I'm using a userspace TCP stack and I send a `syn:true, ack:false` to a website:

```
[2021-06-20T19:30:24Z DEBUG async_smoltcp::packet_log] PHY >>>>
[2021-06-20T19:30:24Z DEBUG async_smoltcp::packet_log] IP [192, 168, 1, 2] -> [13, 224, 38, 134]
[2021-06-20T19:30:24Z DEBUG async_smoltcp::packet_log] TCP: 47675 -> 80 syn: true, ack: false
```

sometimes it works, but sometimes I get a `syn:false, ack:true`:

```
[2021-06-20T19:30:25Z DEBUG async_smoltcp::packet_log] PHY <<<<
[2021-06-20T19:30:25Z DEBUG async_smoltcp::packet_log] IP [13, 224, 38, 134] -> [192, 168, 1, 2]
[2021-06-20T19:30:25Z DEBUG async_smoltcp::packet_log] TCP: 80 -> 47675 syn: false, ack: true
[2021-06-20T19:30:25Z DEBUG smoltcp::socket::tcp] #0:0.0.0.0:47675:13.224.38.134:80: expecting a SYN|ACK
[2021-06-20T19:30:25Z TRACE smoltcp::socket::tcp] #0:0.0.0.0:47675:13.224.38.134:80: state=SYN-SENT=>CLOSED
[2021-06-20T19:30:25Z DEBUG smoltcp::iface::interface] cannot process ingress packet: dropped by socket
```

I tried other websites but this happens to all of them. I do not try to reconnect when this happens. Is this normal? Why some websites do this?

Comment: Sorry, host configurations/issues and networks not under your control are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A server will respond with a `syn:false, ack:true` when it already has an established connection.

You're likely re-using source ports without cleanly closing the connection.